# Cache will be updated or not if there is update available in the network(progressive web app). if yes then how?

Tags: javascript

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0Stc.png)

Cache will be updated or not if there is update available in the network(progressive web app). if yes then how ?

(e-commerce scenario)Suppose client is accessing the same path for 3rd and 4th time and the network receives some updates for that path(consider you are looking for mobile phones in flipkart) .But the thing is in cached memory the searched data has been stored and the network has the updates,

so, if we access the same path for repeated times ,service worker will fetch data from local storage with the updated data or the data which is already stored during the previous visit ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here's a good description](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching?hl=en)

It boils down to:

When you get a resource(ex. HTML or JavaScript file) using http/GET, the response can include two properties:

- `Cache-Control: max-age=[number of seconds]`
- `ETag: [some code or hash]`

`max-age` tells the browser for how many seconds to use the cache instead of sending a new http/GET request for the resource.

Once the max-age time has been passed the browser sends the http/GET request including the `ETag`. The server then checks its resource to see if the `ETag` still matches the one sent from the browser. If it matches, the server sends a `304 Not Modified` response saving network bandwidth. If not, it sends the resource again, updating the browser cache for the new time specified in `max-age`.

For a live example go to the developer console of your browser while looking at this answer (Press CTRL+SHIFT+I if you're using chrome). Reload the page. Go to the `Network` tab, and use the filter to find `favicon`. Click on it and you will see the response and request headers as shown in the image below:

[image]

Notice the `Cache-Control` and `Etag` http header elements.

Comment: could you elaborate using real time example , if possible ?

Comment: added a real-time example for this stack-overflow site : ) The web is a fantastic place!